# Remove clipping region from html5 canvas

Tags: html, canvas, html5-canvas, draw

I'm developing a drawing app , I would put some stencils ( Shape masks  ) so that the User can draw above , in the mask format. I can add the stencil ( clipping region) , but I can not remove it . I wonder how can i remove this clipping region from canvas and leave only the draw that the user did it. Here is the code that i use to add the stencil (region clipping):

Obs: I would like to remove (live) it and leave only the draw that the user made inside it.

Link to jsFiddle: [Link to app on Js Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/marcelbonfim182/mb8gkftp/3/)

```
document.getElementById("addstencil").addEventListener("click", addstencil_funcao);

function addstencil_funcao() {


// layer1/Path
  context.save();
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(285.0, 279.0);
  context.lineTo(0.0, 279.0);
  context.lineTo(0.0, 0.0);
  context.lineTo(285.0, 0.0);
  context.lineTo(285.0, 279.0);
  context.globalAlpha=0.3; //Opacidade da empresa
  context.closePath();
  context.fill();

  // layer1/Path
  context.beginPath();
  context.moveTo(211.4, 242.2);
  context.lineTo(144.0, 206.8);
  context.lineTo(76.6, 242.2);
  context.lineTo(89.5, 167.2);
  context.lineTo(35.0, 114.0);
  context.lineTo(110.3, 103.1);
  context.lineTo(144.0, 34.8);
  context.lineTo(177.7, 103.1);
  context.lineTo(253.0, 114.0);
  context.lineTo(198.5, 167.2);
  context.lineTo(211.4, 242.2);
  context.closePath();
  context.fillStyle = "transparent";
  context.fill();
  context.restore();
  context.clip();



var canvasPic = new Image();
canvasPic.src = imagem_source;
context.drawImage(canvasPic, 0, 0);
}
```

Comment: Only wrapping the `.clip` in `.save` and `.restore` will clear a clipping region (or resizing the canvas also clear a clip). So the proper order is: .save, .beginPath, lots of path commands (no strokes/fills), .clip, stroke/fill, .restore. BTW, fillStyle='transparent' will not clear pixels -- it simply leaves existing pixels unchanged. Cheers!

Comment: Man, thank you! It worked, removed the clipping area ( mask ), but I could not remove the fill of the clipping area (not drawable area of the star, black opaque part) and leave only painting I've done inside. Any idea how can I do this ?  "https://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/YhUs-qH6PT7H1rJ3lh97QNMTjNZETYmyPJy0liipFm0?feat=directlink" Link to a print of app drawing
Obs: The idea is to create a graffiti stencil.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only wrapping the .clip in .save and .restore will clear a clipping region (or resizing the canvas also clear a clip). So the proper order is: .save, .beginPath, lots of path commands (no strokes/fills), .clip, stroke/fill, .restore.

BTW, `fillStyle='transparent'` will not clear pixels -- it simply leaves existing pixels unchanged. You can "erase" pixels by setting `globalCompositeOperation = 'destination-out'` and filling the desired erasure path. Here's an example:

```js
var canvas=document.getElementById("canvas");
var context=canvas.getContext("2d");
var cw=canvas.width;
var ch=canvas.height;

// layer1/Path
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(285.0, 279.0);
context.lineTo(0.0, 279.0);
context.lineTo(0.0, 0.0);
context.lineTo(285.0, 0.0);
context.lineTo(285.0, 279.0);
context.globalAlpha=0.3; //Opacidade da empresa
context.closePath();
context.fill();
context.globalAlpha=1.00;

// layer1/Path
context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(211.4, 242.2);
context.lineTo(144.0, 206.8);
context.lineTo(76.6, 242.2);
context.lineTo(89.5, 167.2);
context.lineTo(35.0, 114.0);
context.lineTo(110.3, 103.1);
context.lineTo(144.0, 34.8);
context.lineTo(177.7, 103.1);
context.lineTo(253.0, 114.0);
context.lineTo(198.5, 167.2);
context.lineTo(211.4, 242.2);
context.closePath();
context.globalCompositeOperation='destination-out';
context.fill();
context.globalCompositeOperation='source-over';
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=300 height=300></canvas>
```

Comment: Man, thank you! It worked, removed the clipping area ( mask ) and restores the canvas context to the original state, but I could not remove (erase) the fill of the clipping area (the "not drawable area of the star", black opaque part) and leave only painting I've done inside. Any idea how can I do this ?  Obs: The idea is to create a graffiti stencil for a drawing app.